# Move docs from one index to another

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to move docs from one index to a different index, without maintaining the source docs.

I'm using scroll to do this now, but, so far, I'm reindexing and it's keeping the source documents on the source index. I don't want this to happen, I want a move not a copy...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no existing functionality to do this.  If you no longer want the source document in the source index, you'll need to delete the document.

The source isn't stored separately in some kind of blob which indices "point" at.  The source is an integral part of the index, so you can't move it...just copy.

Sorry :(

Comment: I feared this would be the answer. Can I at least delete the doc using the bulk API and refrencing by the entire doc?

Comment: Yeah, bulk supports deletions.  You just need the index/type/ID of the document(s) that you want to delete.